# GCP PHP App Engine - NGINX 404 when using custom runtime

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Lumen/Laravel API application that when I deploy it to App Engine Flex using the default PHP runtime, the application works fine.

However, when I use a custom runtime (Using the base PHP runtime), I keep getting an NGINX 404 error which I don't understand as I'm only adding 1 extra library in the Dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/php

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y libdmtx-utils
```

app.yml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
resources:
  cpu: 0.1
  memory_gb: 0.6
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
readiness_check:
  app_start_timeout_sec: 3000
runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  front_controller_file: index.php
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, your image is being deployed, but there is no code deploy on it, this is reason why you are getting a 404.

You should be adding your application code in the Dockerfile. Check some of the examples on the [git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples) for App Engine Custom runtime over here if you want to check how this is done.

Additionally, check the paths on your app.yaml file so that you are pointing to the correct folders for your application.

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Such a noob error, I was there thinking the GCP image would pick up the files. In the end I made my own Dockerfile: https://pastebin.com/QJe8t2gr Thank you for your help and preventing me from spending days on this issue